# Working Quick Look Plugins For Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

Trying to find reliable info on working quicklook plugins for Mountain Lion.

I'd like to at least find working ones for colour code syntax highlight in source code previews, and preview plain text files like "README" without a file extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Xcode, most source code files are shown (albeit without color) natively. The "without a file extension" makes things interesting since unless the file is typed, quicklook (and the spotlight importer responsible for determining what type of file each one actually is) has less context to decide how to classify a blank README file.

Have a look at t[he qlcolorcode plug in](http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/) for colored syntax quick look and [QLStephen](http://www.quicklookplugins.com/2011/08/22/qlstephen/) for README and other ASCII plain text files.

Comment: I'd recommend against QLStephen as it tends to do a text dump of everything.

Comment: @CyberSkull great info about QLStephen. I don't use it much anymore and don't know if there are improved ones out.

Comment: I tried it some months ago, it basically acts as a "catch-all" for any file type not covered by any other plugin, and for a few that are.