# Is there a way to get OSX Finder to search through .ts (textscript) files?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search, metadata

I really like using OSX's finder to quickly find a particular file and its content based on search, I need to work on in my web projects. We often have 100s upon 100s of separate files and I need to quickly find files quickly.

OSX's Finder works on `.html` and `.scss` files wonderfully on my system. However, it doesn't seem to want to search inside of `.ts` files. Is there a way to enable this in OSX?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Quicklook and Spotlight need to know how to look into a ".ts" file. Sounds like they are (essentiually...) a text file but you need a way to tell macOS that.

Over on Stack Exchange there was [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320092/how-do-i-register-a-new-extension-with-quicklook-in-mac-os-10-7) to a *similar* question that might be of help to you. It does involve a project on GitHub and may involve some programming skills on your part to make it work with ".ts" files, but it seems like a start, at least...

Answer (score 2):

You can try the app [EasyFind.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) This app is free on the app stores and you can tell it the extension of the files you want to do a text search. It's a very useful app to search your disk and files. When you start EasyFind click on the Settings icon in the top left corner of the EasyFind pane. It's there that you tell the app to search on .ts files.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a life saver for me. And it's so simple, yet so powerful.

```
grep -r "Search for this phrase" /in/the/files/in/this/directory
```

Here is an the example output for a folder contain the following

- **File 1**: "Hello. This is Bob. Whats going on?"
- **File 2**: "Please upvote my answer. I would really appreciate it"
- **File 3**: "Bob has two B's in it. Did you know that?"

  $ grep -r "Bob" ~/Desktop/test
  /Users/jbis/Desktop/test/File 1:Hello. This is Bob. Whats going on?
  /Users/jbis/Desktop/test/File 3:Bob has two B's in it. Did you know that?

`grep` will find and print the file and line that the phrase is found.

**Note:** This is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely this is possible. You just need to install an app with a quick look plug in to claim those files.

- [Working Quick Look Plugins For Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92562/working-quick-look-plugins-for-mountain-lion)

Start with the plug in listed above and consider posting the results of what `mdls` has to say about the file metadata for your .ts files if you can’t find a tool to get spotlight to index these without messing with the file extensions. Since Microsoft also may have an interest in these files, try installing visual studio code and see if it has spotlight importers to assist in indexing the contents of those files on your Mac.